# IBM Db2 Expected tokens may include: "JOIN <joined_table>". SQLSTATE=426

Tags: javascript, sql, db2

When I try to query my local DB if I try to do it via an API by passing it a string like this:

```
conn.query(stri ,(err, data) =>{
               if (err) console.log(err);
               else console.log(data);
               conn.close(() => console.log('done'));
           });
```

he gives me the following error:

> [SERVER] { Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An 
>   unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following 
>   "'5020.52','300.00')"".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN 
>   ".  SQLSTATE=42601 [SERVER] [SERVER]   errors: [], 
>   [SERVER]   error: '[node-ibm_db] SQL_ERROR', [SERVER]   message: 
>   '[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token 
>   "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "\'5020.52\',\'300.00\')"".
>   Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN ".
>   SQLSTATE=42601\r\n', [SERVER]   state: '42601' } [SERVER] done 
>   [SERVER] POST /api/db2 - - ms - - [SERVER] { Error: [IBM][CLI 
>   Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token 
>   "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "'5020.52','300.00')"".
>   Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN ".  SQLSTATE=42601 
>   [SERVER] [SERVER]   errors: [], [SERVER]   error: '[node-ibm_db] 
>   SQL_ERROR', [SERVER]   message: '[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] 
>   SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following 
>   "\'5020.52\',\'300.00\')"".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN 
>   ".  SQLSTATE=42601\r\n', [SERVER]   state: '42601' }

The same string if launched from the command line not from errors

> db2@test-db2:~$ db2 "INSERT INTO db2.STAFF VALUES
>   ('370','Chri','84','Sales','20','5020.52','300.00')" DB20000I  The SQL
>   command completed successfully.

in the "stri" varaible there is this string:

> "INSERT INTO db2.STAFF VALUES
>   ('370','Chri','84','Sales','20','5020.52','300.00')"

Someone can help me? :)

Comment: Are you saying that double quotes are part of the value of `stri`?

Comment: Yes, but i fix it removing precisely the "" from the variable stri